# Media Url returns error 500 django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

have the following problem, I have in my settings.py configured in the following way:

```
RUTA_PROYECTO = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(RUTA_PROYECTO,'fotos')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In my urls file I have:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

Urlpatterns = patterns ('',
....
) + static (settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have in my models

```
def upload_name(instance, filename):
return '{}/{}'.format(instance.persona.nro_doc, filename)

class FotosPersona(models.Model):
    persona        = models.ForeignKey(Personas,related_name='fotos_persona')
    tipo_foto      = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    foto           = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_name)
    fecha          = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'fotos_persona'
```

When I save the data, the image is stored in a folder within the following structure:

```
Project
 |
 |
 |----Project
         |---- settings.py
         |---- media
         |---- urls.py
         .....
```

But when I want to display the image in a template, it is not displayed.

When in the browser I entered the

http://localhost:8000/media/other_folder/image_file.jpg url

it returns me an HTTP 500 error.

Comment: i assume you have debug set to true, so what's the error's traceback?

Comment: Can you show the error log ?

Comment: Find what is the problem, in my urls I have this line at the end of the list (r '^', 'prevtivos.views.page_not_found'), if I remove it I can see the images, but it takes me to a page of not found.

Comment: When that line is included, on entering http://localhost:800, it returns a page of not found, if it is not included it returns the standard page of 404 of django.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is a little late, but this might be useful considering your set up. Essentially, you have given the MEDIA_URL as "/media/". This is all right.

However, you would be facing a problem with reference to the URL patterns. You will probably have a generic URL along the lines of:

```
path('<index>', views.index, name='index'),
```

In such a scenario this URL would be processing everything that comes from the media URL. Although this is not ideal, *only* for the purpose of **development** I would recommend changing your URL patterns to the following:

```
urlpatterns = static (settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + [
    ...
    ]
```

Now in the hierarchy of processing URL patterns "/media/" would come before any URL that has a general pattern. Now media URLs would be processed before everything else.

Hopefully, this can address your query.